# How to insert a row using Azure Mobile Easy Tables in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sql-insert, azure-mobile-services

How to insert a record into an Azure Mobile table without going through the magical CRUD API?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

```
req.azureMobile.tables('User')
    .insert({email: "example@example.com"})
    .then(function (insertedItem) {
        var id = insertedItem.id;
        console.log("inserted user", id)
    }, function(err) {
        console.error("Could not insert user:", err);
    });
```